# Proper use and interpretation of chi-squared test

Tags: distributions, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Please help me understanding basic features of [chi-squared test for distribution comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).
As far as I understand, if we draw two samples from the same distribution, **and treat one sample as "observed" and another as "expected"** then
most of the time the associated chi2 value will be low and the respective p-value to reject the null hypothesis that the two samples come from the same distribution will be high. Therefore, I expect that if I repeat this process many times 
and test this p-value against some predefined threshold (say 0.05), then only a in a small fraction of times (~5% in our case) 
the associated p-value will be below the critical threshold. However, in my simulations this null hypothesis is rejected in about 23% of sample pairs.
What am I missing?
Below is my Python code. In this code, i generate two samples of 100 random integers between 0 and 3. I then calculate the p-value using my implementation of chi2 tests
(I verified the correctness of my chi2 
test function against [an online calculator](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/chisquared2.cfm)) and compare this value to a threshold (ALPHA = 0.05). I repeat this process 
1000 times and calculate the percentage of times where the p-value was below ALPHA

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
def chi2testTwoSamples(observed, expected):
    countO = defaultdict(int)
    countE = defaultdict(int)
    nPoints = len(observed)
    assert nPoints == len(expected)
    for o in observed: countO[o] += 1
    for e in expected: countE[e] += 1

    keysO = set(countO.keys())
    keysE = set(countE.keys())
    keys = list(keysO.union(keysE))
    keys.sort()
    countExpected = np.array([countE[k] for k in keys], dtype=float) 
    countObserved = np.array([countO[k] for k in keys], dtype=float) 
    sel = (countExpected != 0)
    countExpected = countExpected[sel]
    countObserved = countObserved[sel]
    chi2 = np.sum((countExpected - countObserved) ** 2 / countExpected)
    df = len(keys) - 1
    pVal = 1.0 - stats.distributions.chi2.cdf(chi2, df)
    return (chi2, pVal)



TIMES = 1000
SAMPLES = 100
ALPHA = 0.05
timesBelowAlpha = 0
np.random.seed(9999)
for i in range(TIMES):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 3, SAMPLES) #draw many integers between 0 and 3
    b = np.random.randint(0, 3, SAMPLES)
    p = chi2testTwoSamples(a, b)[1]
    if p < ALPHA:
        timesBelowAlpha += 1
percentage = 100.0 * timesBelowAlpha / TIMES
print '%.1f%%'%(percentage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hardly read Python but what I understand from the code of your `chi2testTwoSamples` function is that you consider the second sample as "expected values"; that’s not the way it works!

- Either you compare the four observed values $n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3$ obtained from counts of a single random sample of $N$ elements in $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ with the expected values $e_0 = e_1 = e_2 = e_3 = {1\over 4} N$ ;
- or you have two samples of total size $N$ (resp. $M$) with counts $n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3$ (resp. $m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3$), and assuming that both samples come from the same distribution you infer the frequencies $f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3$ of the four outcomes by $f_i = {1 \over N+M} (n_i + m_i)$ and expected values are $N f_i$ (resp. $M f_i$).

In both cases, the result should follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with $3$ degrees of freedom. The computation of the number of degrees of freedom is different in the two cases, it’s not every time as simple as *number of categories - 1*...

Comment: you understood my code correctly. Can you please clarify what are the N and M variables in your second bullet point?

Comment: @bgbg The total size of the two samples, $N = n_0 + n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ and $M = m_0 + m_1 + m_2 + m_3$. In your case $N = M = 100$.